# Short Javascript script to detect if an item value with yes then redirect sharepoint page?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, javascript, jquery

Is there a way to place a small JQuery/Javascript code to detect if an item list value is equal to yes and if so redirect the page using Content Editor Webpart?

```
If "Status=no"
 Then <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.com/" />
```

The hard part is reading the item list value and integrating that into JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I summarize your requirement, Then It is

1. Get Items from a list using JavaScript
2. Redirect to some *URL*

## Get Items Using JSOM

You can use CAML query for this as you need to filter `Status=no`. So the query should look like

```
<View>
   <Query>
      <Where>
        <Eq><FieldRef Name=\"Status\" />
           <Value Type=\"Text\">no</Value>
        </Eq>
      </Where>
    </Query>
</View>
```

**Sample code**

```
function retrieveListItems() {

    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext('Site Url');
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('List Name');

    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"Status\" /><Value Type=\"Text\">no</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>');
    this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);

    clientContext.load(collListItem);

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));

}

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {

    var listItemInfo = '';

    var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();

    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
        listItemInfo += '\nID: ' + oListItem.get_id() +
            '\nTitle: ' + oListItem.get_item('Title') +
            '\nStatus: ' + oListItem.get_item('Status');
    }

    alert(listItemInfo.toString());
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

For more explanation [How to: Retrieve List Items Using JavaScript](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh185007(v=office.14).aspx)

## Redirect to some *URL*

```
window.location.href = 'http://example.com/';
```

Comment: Thank you Atish! Please forgive by letting me, since this is for one page, where do I place the code above? In a CEWP? Thank you!

Comment: This is a little new to me. Please tell me , is the aforementioned code to be placed in a CEWP. Furthermore I can't ascertain where the retrieved fields are stored.

Comment: From which page you need to redirect. You can put this code into that page